# Configure Google instead of S-Voice

Tags: google, samsung-galaxy-s-5

My s5 allows me to have S-Voice always listening for its hot word. I would rather have Google always listening for its  hot word. I don't see how to do this. Any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest updates to Google Voice allow me to "OK google" from any awake screen, even the 'swipe' screen as long as the device isn't locked. Even works from within many third party apps! Thanks Goog!

Answer (score 0):

You can reach the Google voice settings by going to Apps -> Google Settings -> Search & Now -> Voice -> Ok Google hot word detection and turning the switch to "On" Google hot word detection only works from the home page where the Google search box is located.  If you don't have a Google search box, you can get one from your widgets which is accessible by touching and holding the home page with your finger.

Comment: Yep thanks for answering but I know all of that, I have the widget and I use the hot word. I'm looking to have it always listening.

Comment: Always listening is based on a special chip that is 'always listening' out for the key word. The Moto G (or is it X) has this and the Nexus 5... Not the Galaxy S5. There is a hacked Google Search, you need to install a lot of files and mess around to get it working, and even then expect your battery to last about 2 hours with it running, the device simply isn't made for this.

Comment: I looked at an app called S for Switch Voice Free that suppose to take advantage of the "Always Listening" chip on the Galaxy S5. The app developer claims that it will start Google Now. I haven't tried it but you can find it in the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same frustrations with my Note 3 back in the fall when it was new. I solved it by creating an app first for myself then made it available on the Play Store.

But first, on the S5 you have to enable car mode for voice wake-up to work.

Then you can install the app [S for Switch Voice Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.viczian.deathtosvoice) to have Google Voice Search (ie Google Now) answer your commands.

[image]

And finally you can now have something similar to MotoX touchless control using the app [Touchless Notifications Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.viczian.notifications.free) which does handsfree notification announcement and has something like the new "What's up" feature on the Motorola ~ if you give the command "Open my notifications" it will read-out the active notifications with pretty good looking display...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per [phandroid](http://phandroid.com/2014/10/17/galaxy-note-4-first-13-things/) we have this, which I have just confirmed works:

1. Settings > Language and input > Voice Search > “Ok Google ”
2. Detection Check all 3 boxes Train the voice recognition by saying
   Okay Google 3 times (say it a bit differently each time to improve
   accuracy)